# Using {redirect=""} to redirect to an external website

Tags: redirects

We're trying to use redirect to allow our website editors to link to external pages, however when we use:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
  {redirect='{external_link}'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It just takes them to http://example.com//http://www.myredirecturl.com

Is it possible to use redirect to link to external websites? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not with a tag, but with a PHP snippet you can, you have some options:

1. Using EE's built on function

   ```
   <?php ee()->functions->redirect('{external_link}'); ?>
   ```

You'll need **PHP parsing on**, if you want to use the `{external_link}` tag you'll have to set it to run on **Output**

2. Location Header redirect.

With the above you may get some screen artifacts as the template engine runs before the redirect. you can avoid this with a bog standard PHP redirect. Commonly known as a

```
<?php header('Location: {external_link}'); exit; ?>
```

This method you'll also need **PHP on Output**, so you can parse the `{external_link}` tag in the PHP snippet, but this should abort the template engine and redirect a bit cleaner. Make sure this statement is executed BEFORE you send anything to the browser.

3. You could always set up a JS redirect and push the tag into some script, means loading the page before redirecting though, but no need for PHP parsing:

My personal favourite is option 2.

Answer (score 2):

Why just using either snippet or direct put to template meta-part instead of using PHP in-template if editors put full URL?

Something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries}
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={external_link}">
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Yep, this is also totally valid, option 3. Thanks Riverboy